# why does my main method keeps running?

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-integration

I´m doing a spring-integration + rabbitMQ application. From a main class I call a gateway that sends to a rabbitmq my message and it works perfectly but for some weird reason my main method keeps on running, at first I tought that I may have left a poller in my spring-context but that´s not the case. 
Here is my code:

```
public final class Main {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Main.class);

    @Autowired
    static
    ChatGateway chatGateway;

    private Main() { }

    /**
     * Load the Spring Integration Application Context
     *
     * @param args - command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Mensaje mensaje = new Mensaje();
        mensaje.setClienteID("clienteXXX");

        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new 
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:META-INF/spring/integration/spring-integration-context.xml");
        chatGateway = (ChatGateway) ctx.getBean("chatGateway");

        chatGateway.enviarAlarma(mensaje);

    }
}
```

and here is my spring context:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:int-amqp="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/amqp"
    xmlns:rabbit="http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit"
    xmlns:int-stream="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/amqp http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/amqp/spring-integration-amqp.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream/spring-integration-stream.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit/spring-rabbit.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <!-- From STDIN To RabbitMQ 

    <int-stream:stdin-channel-adapter id="consoleIn"
        channel="toRabbit">
        <int:poller fixed-delay="1000" max-messages-per-poll="1" />
    </int-stream:stdin-channel-adapter>
    -->

    <int:channel id="toRabbit" />

    <int:gateway id="chatGateway"
        service-interface="com.praxis.chat.gateway.ChatGateway"
        default-request-channel="toRabbit" />

    <int-amqp:outbound-channel-adapter
        channel="toRabbit" amqp-template="amqpTemplate" exchange-name="si.test.exchange"
        routing-key="si.test.binding" />


    <!-- Infrastructure -->

    <rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory" />

    <rabbit:template id="amqpTemplate" connection-factory="connectionFactory" />

    <rabbit:admin connection-factory="connectionFactory" />

    <rabbit:queue name="si.test.queue" />

    <rabbit:direct-exchange name="si.test.exchange">
        <rabbit:bindings>
            <rabbit:binding queue="si.test.queue" key="si.test.binding" />
        </rabbit:bindings>
    </rabbit:direct-exchange>

</beans>
```

Why does my main method keeps on running even after it sent the message??
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will keep going, because it hasn't been told to end.

You could use:

`System.exit(0);`

or

`return;`

at the end of `main(String[] args)`

Comment: That seems to do the work. I tought that a main method wouldn´t be finished unless it had an infinite loop.

Comment: Actually, the issue is that the RabbitMQ client runs a non-daemon thread When you are ready to shutdown your application, you can use `ctx.destroy()` which will invoke `destroy()` on the connection factory, closing the connection and stopping the connection's thread.